# Retrieve rows satisfying any one condition or both conditions

Tags: sql-server

I've table named **EMPLOYEE** which contains **First Name**, **Last Name** and **Employee ID**. Now I want to get rows when I search for **First Name** alone or **Last name** alone or may be both. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use dynamic queries:

```
DECLARE @FirstName NVARCHAR(50), @LastName NVARCHAR(50);
SET @FirstName = 'John';
SET @LastName = 'Johnson';

DECLARE @SqlStatement NVARCHAR(MAX), @SqlParamters NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @SqlStatement = N'SELECT e.EmployeeID, e.FirstName, e.LastName FROM dbo.Employee e
' 
+ CASE WHEN @FirstName IS NOT NULL OR @LastName IS NOT NULL THEN 'WHERE '
+ CASE WHEN @FirstName IS NOT NULL THEN 'e.FirstName = @pFirstName'
+ CASE WHEN @LastName IS NOT NULL THEN 'e.LastName = @pLastName';

-- PRINT @SqlStatement;

EXEC sp_executesql 
    @SqlStatement, 
    N'@pFirstName NVARCHAR(50), @pLastName NVARCHAR(50)',
    @pFirstName = @FirstName,
    @pLastName = @LastName;
```

Indexing: if you have the following index

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Employee_LastName_FirstName
On dbo.Employee (LastName, FirstName);
```

then only the following predicates are SARGable (Index Seek):

```
WHERE e.LastName = @pLastName
```

and

```
WHERE e.LastName = @pLastName AND e.FirstName = @pFirstName
```

but the following predicate isn't SARGable (Index Scan):

```
WHERE e.FirstName = @pFirstName
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query. I assume you have 2 paramers `@FirstName` and `@LastName` which can be NULL if you don't want to search by them.

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE ([First Name] = @FirstName OR @FirstName IS NULL)
    AND ([Last Name] = @LastName OR @LastName IS NULL)
```